# Run Ghost in a subdirectory of my main Node.js application

Tags: node.js, azure, nginx, ghost-blog

I am trying to run Ghost on a subdirectory of my main Node.js project. It is currently hosted in azure websites. 
Something like:
http://randomurlforpost.azurewebsites.net/blog

I followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Using-Ghost-as-an-NPM-module

With the new addition of using Ghost as a npm module do I still need Nginx or Apache?. As of now I have my main site running on localhost:3000 and the Ghost instance running on localhost:2368.

I have tried doing all kinds of modifications to the part of the code stated on the instructions however I have not succeeded.

```js
//app.js, is there a specific place to put this?

var ghost = require('ghost');
ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
    ghostServer.start();
});

//config.js
    development: {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/blog',
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
            filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghostdev.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2368'
        },
        paths: {
            contentPath: path.join(__dirname, '/content/'),
        }
    },
//index.js
ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {

    parentApp.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir,ghostServer.rootApp);

    // Let ghost handle starting our server instance.
    ghostServer.start(parentApp);
}).catch(function (err) {
    errors.logErrorAndExit(err, err.context, err.help);
});
```

**EDIT**: I was able to route traffic with *http-proxy* however it is routing it to localhost:2368/blog (which doesn't exist) any ideas on how to prevent this?

```js
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var blogProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var ghost     = require('ghost');
var path      = require('path');

// Route /blog* to Ghost
router.get("/blog*", function(req, res, next){ 
    blogProxy.ws(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:2368' });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having the same issue and first tried using Apache's ProxyPass to redirect `/blog` to `port 2368` but found other issues doing this.

Before trying my suggestions you should undo any changes made using `httpproxy`.

What seems to have worked for me is placing the code you have in `index.js` directly into your `app.js` file instead of what you already have in there. You will need to add the ghost errors variable and rename `parentApp` to the name of your app, I'll call this `yourAppName` so it's clear but mine is just `app`. So inside `app.js` you can put:

```js
var yourAppName = express();
var ghost = require('ghost');
var ghosterrors = require('ghost/core/server/errors')

ghost().then(function(ghostServer) {
  yourAppName.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir, ghostServer.rootApp);

  ghostServer.start(yourAppName);
}).catch(function(err) {
  errors.logErrorAndExit(err, err.context, err.help);
});
```

You probably already have the `ghost` and `express` variables declared in app.js so you won't need to add these lines.

The blog should now be available at the URL specified in config.js.